# Inserir valor num array

Tags: php

Boas, estou a tentar inserir um valor num array que recebo de uma base de dados.

O array contem um conjunto de arrays sendo que cada array desse conjunto corresponde a uma viatura.
Eu quero pegar em dois valores de cada viatura, calcular a diferença e de seguida criar um valor no array dessa viatura com a diferença calculada.

Eu estou a tentar fazer da seguinte maneira :

```
foreach ($viaturas as $key => $viatura) {
    if ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao1']) {
        $diff = $viatura['inspecao1'] - $viatura['kms'];
    } elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao2']) {
        $diff = $viatura['inspecao2'] - $viatura['kms'];
    } elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao3']) {
        $diff = $viatura['inspecao3'] - $viatura['kms'];
    } elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao4']) {
        $diff = $viatura['inspecao4'] - $viatura['kms'];
    } elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao5']) {
        $diff = $viatura['inspecao5'] - $viatura['kms'];
    } elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao6']) {
        $diff = $viatura['inspecao6'] - $viatura['kms'];
    } elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao7']) {
        $diff = $viatura['inspecao7'] - $viatura['kms'];
    } elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao8']) {
        $diff = $viatura['inspecao8'] - $viatura['kms'];
    } elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao9']) {
        $diff = $viatura['inspecao9'] - $viatura['kms'];
    } elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao10']) {
        $diff = $viatura['inspecao10'] - $viatura['kms'];
    }
    array_push($viatura, $diff);
}
```

Mas ele não acrescenta o valor no fim de cada viatura, o que é que estou a fazer de errado?

Também já tentei usar `$viatura['diff'] = $diff;` mas não resultou

Comment: Depois de `$viatura['diff'] = $diff;` vc imprimiu todo o resultado depois do `foreach`?

Comment: já resolvi o problema, meti a resposta no post. Obrigado na mesma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu estava a fazer um print da variável $viaturas em vez de criar um array novo com os dados de $viaturas e juntar-lhe-ia a variável $diff o que, por razões óbvias, não me estava a mostrar a variável diff no array.

Basicamente, no final de percorrer cada viatura iria adiciona-la a um array $veiculos que no final iria ter as mesmas viaturas com o valor da variável $diff.

Resolvido:

```
$viaturas = $this->Viatura_model->readall();
    foreach ($viaturas as $key => $viatura) {
        if($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao1']){
            $diff = $viatura['inspecao1'] -$viatura['kms'];
        }elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao2']) {
            $diff = $viatura['inspecao2'] -$viatura['kms'];
        }elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao3']) {
            $diff = $viatura['inspecao3'] -$viatura['kms'];
        }elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao4']) {
            $diff = $viatura['inspecao4'] -$viatura['kms'];
        }elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao5']) {
            $diff = $viatura['inspecao5'] -$viatura['kms'];
        }elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao6']) {
            $diff = $viatura['inspecao6'] -$viatura['kms'];
        }elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao7']) {
            $diff = $viatura['inspecao7'] -$viatura['kms'];
        }elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao8']) {
            $diff = $viatura['inspecao8'] -$viatura['kms'];
        }elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao9']) {
            $diff = $viatura['inspecao9'] -$viatura['kms'];
        }elseif ($viatura['kms'] < $viatura['inspecao10']) {
            $diff = $viatura['inspecao10'] -$viatura['kms'];
        }
        $viatura['diff'] = $diff;
        $veiculos[] = $viatura; 
    }
```